# How to flatten the nested calls in RXJS and finally invoke one last call?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, rxjs, nested

How best we can flatten the below calls. New to RxJS, trying to understand how it should be simplified. Read flatMap, forkJoin, switchMap and mergeMap, not getting a right path to integrate it below and not sure which is best in the below scenario.

```
const useful = [];

a.get('abc').
subscribe((abcdatas) => {

   abcdatas.forEach(abcdata => {
     if(abcdata.exist) {
        b.get('def').
        subscribe((defdatas) => {
           useful.push(defdatas.someval);
        });
      } 
   });

 })

if(useful.length) {
 c.get('ghi').
 subscribe((ghidata) => {
   completed...
 });
}
```

### Update

Updating my question here and thanks for all the responses. The useful is an global array of result that should be populated from nested call in my case. And it should be passed to the last call finally.

Steps which I am trying:

1. a.get() => returns adata
2. b.get(adataset) => should perform a request for every adataset if adataset has exist attribute and also populate useful array which will be used later
3. c.get(useful) => should trigger and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mapping function like `switchMap` or `mergeMap` to map the result from one request to the next request. Use `forkJoin` to execute multiple requests simultaneously.

So for a one to many scenario the general idea is:

```ts
firstRequest().pipe(
  switchMap(results => forkJoin(results.map(r => nextRequest(r))))
)
```

For your case that would be something like:

```ts
useful = [];

a.get('abc').pipe(
  switchMap(abcdatas => forkJoin(getUseFulRequests(abcdatas))),
  tap(useful => useful.forEach(u => this.useful.push(u))),
  switchMap(useful => useful.length ? c.get('ghi') : EMPTY)
).subscribe((ghidata) => {
  completed...
});


function getUseFulRequests(abcdatas: AbcData[]): Observable<SomeVal>[] {
  return abcdatas.reduce((acc, abcdata) => {
    if (abcdata.exist) {
      const request = b.get('def').pipe(
        map(defdatas => defdatas.someval)
      )
      acc.push(request);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

This won't emit anything if `getUseFulRequests(abcdatas)` returns an empty array or `useful.length == 0`.

Comment: Appreciate your response

Comment: useful is not just for useful requests, it is array formed by the second call i. b.get()

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa you can use `tap` to populate your global array from an intermediate response.

Comment: Example please, as i told i am new and its taking time for me to come out of axios and async, await and promises

Comment: thank you, i learnt something very useful from your answer and makes clean call for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to handle this will be to use higher order observables

Consider below code

```
useful$ = a.get('abc').pipe(
  mergeMap(abcdatas => 
    abcdata.exist ? forkJoin(abcdatas.map(abcdata => b.get('def'))) : of(undefined)
  ),
  map(defdatas => defdatas.flat()),
  mergeMap(({ length }) => length ? c.get('ghi') : of(undefined))
);

useful$.subscribe({
  next: () => { 
    // Completed...
  }
})
```

We first pipe the result of `a.get('abc')` and use mergeMap to test if `abcdata.exist`. If it does exits we return `forkJoin(abcdatas.map(abcdata => b.get('def')))` simply this will combine an array of observables generated from map function on abcdatas

`map(defdatas => defdatas.flat()),` will transform the array to a single array
**NOTE: flat() was introduces in ES2019**

Next we destructure the `length` property and if it exists we return our final observable

Comment: Appreciate your response

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
a.get("abc").pipe(
  mergeMap((abcdatas) => abcdatas.filter((abcdata) => abcdata.exist)), // let's create a stream with all those useful abcdata
  mergeMap(abcdata => b.get('def')), // and for each one of those we perform a b.get request
  toArray(), // once all the b.get requests have completed, emit a one value stream with an Array of those values values
  concatMap(useful => useful.length ? c.get('ghi') : EMPTY) // let's concat that result with the final request
)
```

Comment: Appreciate your response